# Combining modernizr and selectvizr?

Tags: html, cross-browser, css, modernizr

I'm trying to get cross browser support for my HTML5/CSS3 site with the Selectivizr (for selecting HTML5 elements and check HTML5 browser support) and Modernizr to use CSS3 selectors.
Sadly, combining a css3 selector with a html5 element results in no styling applied.

Offcourse i could easily change my stylesheet so it doesn't contains any CSS3 selectors, but i am wondering if there's a way to use HTML5 elements and CSS3 selectors cross-browser.

Any suggestions on the possibility of this getting to work?

Comment: Did you check that your javascript library supports the selector you're using? [jQuery](http://jquery.com) seems to support the least number of selectors listed on the [selectivr](http://selectivizr.com/) website.

Comment: Yes, i was using last-child which should be supported by jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem, actually selectivizr and modernizr both work nicely together. My stylesheet was depending on child selectors also, which selectivizr (logically, CSS2) doesn't fix.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about this? I'm using :last-child in one of my css classes and IE8 is not picking it up. I'm only using Modernizr?